# Impact of publishing messages to one Kafka broker with in a cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have Kafka cluster with three brokers and zookeeper instances. Kept the replication factor of 2 for each partition.

i want to understand the impact of publishing messages to single node in a cluster by giving one broker address. Will this broker sends message to other brokers if messages fit into partitions hold by other brokers?

can someone explain how internal sync works or else point to resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> giving one broker address

Even if you give one address, the bootstrap protocol returns all brokers to the client.

The partitioner logic determines which partition in which broker to send the data to - you target partitions, not brokers in the client.

Comment: how does it work if client have no access to all brokers?